# XMLHttpRequest GET Server Status is 200 but POST Server Status is 500

Tags: javascript, json, post, get, xmlhttprequest

I am writing a function in Javascript to post JSON data using the XMLHttpRequest POST method. The following code works fine for GET:

```
function httpGet(myurl, cb){
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            if( typeof cb === 'function' )
                cb(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    };

   xmlhttp.open("GET",myurl,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

However, the following code, with the same URL used with GET gives me an xmlhttp status of 500 all the time.

```
function httpPost(myurl,data,cb){

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            if (typeof cb == 'function'){
                cb(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
};

xmlhttp.open("POST",myurl,true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.send(data);
}
```

Comment: 500 is an internal server error, so something happened on the server that made it crap out, and not with your ajax call.

Comment: You need to look at the error on the server. When you look at the Ajax call from the server in your debugger [console or net tab], you should see what that problem is.

Comment: Do you have it set up on you server to only accept `GET` requests at that URL? You said you use the same URL, and the only change between your function is `GET`/`POST` and the `data` passed to it.

Comment: @epascarello: I looked at the Network tab and found out I was missing required fields for the database, derp. Thanks for the help everyone!